# Why is my background image not scaling right?

Tags: modeling, image

I'm trying to use background images for modeling, but some of the images aren't the right scale when i import them. For clarification:

[image]

You can clearly see that both of the images have the right length/width. However, this is the result when I overlap them in blender:

[image: Blender Image]

How is this possible? The size of all images in blender is set to 10.

Comment: What to do that for ? These images should be used in different preset orthographic views; top one - in the top view; side one - in side views. As long as adjacent resolution is the same like in your case it should work. Compare their size relatively to cube in order to check different views.

Comment: I reckon this isn't the regular workflow that you would use. Usually using the import image plane will give a much better workflow since those images are applied on a 3d plane it's much easiler to manipulate and scale. More over the import image plane operation takes your image aspect ratio into consideration so you don't have to worry about them.

Answer (score 1):

It may have something to do with the aspect ratio of the images. Try setting the scale of the vertical image to 5.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of improving the quality of workflow try this instead.

1. Import > Image as planes.

[image: show import image as planes]